# Why is my replacement only producing the last value in a list that I have passed through a function?

Tags: python, list, function, replace

I have a list (letter_grades) that has four "X" in it (each corresponding to a student grade).  I need to use a function to calculate letter grades from a previously existing list (student_grades = [98, 87, 67, 89]).  Finally, I want to take that information and replace the "X" values in letter_grades with the values I got using student_grades.

So, if I calculated that the first student scored 98, the function told me that was an A, I want to replace the X with the A (in the correct order).  In theory I'd end up with letter_grades = A, B, D, B.

I feel like I am really close (but maybe not).  Here is what I have so far.  My issue is that it is only changing the values to the last item in the list.  I assume it's because of how print works, but I am having trouble figuring out how else to solve this.

```
student_grades = [98, 87, 67, 89]
letter_grades = ['X','X','X','X']

def Gradecalc(list):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    else:   
        if score >= 80:
            letter = 'B'
        else:  
            if score >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            else:    
                if score >= 60:
                    letter = 'D'
                else:
                    letter = 'F'
    return letter

for value in range(len(letter_grades)):
        letter_grades[value]=letter_grades[value].replace("X", Gradecalc(student_grades))
    
print(letter_grades)
```

The output just gives me ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'] - which is the last anticipated value of letter_grades.

Am I close?  How do I get it to print the correct values?

Comment: `score` is used but not set in the shown code.

Comment: Why does the `Gradecalc` function not use its argument?

Comment: Honestly, I am not entirely sure... I restarted/ran all and now it's not giving me that anymore...  So now I have no idea how I got the ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'].  I'm sorry, I'll try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code snippet produces errors.
As mentioned in the comment, `score` used but not defined.

Here's how your code can be changed:

```
student_grades = [98, 87, 67, 89]
letter_grades = ['X','X','X','X']

def Gradecalc(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    elif score >= 80:
        letter = 'B'
    elif score >= 70:
        letter = 'C'
    elif score >= 60:
        letter = 'D'
    else:
        letter = 'F'
    return letter

for value in range(len(letter_grades)):
    letter_grades[value] = letter_grades[value].replace("X", Gradecalc(student_grades[value]))
    
print(letter_grades)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'D', 'B']
```

I changed the argument of `Gradecalc` to `score`.

Then changed the calling of `Gradecalc(student_grades)` to `Gradecalc(student_grades[value])` (only one grade, not all of them at one time).

Also, nested `if..else` can be rewritten as `if..elif..else`, makes code more readable.

Comment: Ah!!  That was it - the extra value in the Gradecalc replacement!  I have no idea how I originally got the ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'] but this solved it.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not using the score variable

```
student_grades = [98, 87, 67, 89]
letter_grades = ['X','X','X','X']

def Gradecalc(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    else:   
        if score >= 80:
            letter = 'B'
        else:  
            if score >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            else:    
                if score >= 60:
                    letter = 'D'
                else:
                    letter = 'F'
    return letter

for key,value in enumerate(student_grades):
    letter_grades[key]=letter_grades[key].replace("X", Gradecalc(value))
    
print(letter_grades)
```

You should send every single value into the function Gradecalc to return the value, instead of a list.

The output is:

```
['A', 'B', 'D', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

hey your main problem was that you were passing entire list to the function but checking a variable that has nothing to do with list here is a version that works:

```
student_grades = [98, 87, 67, 89]
letter_grades = ['X','X','X','X']

def Gradecalc(score):

   if score >= 90:
       letter = 'A'
   else:   
       if score >= 80:
           letter = 'B'
       else:  
          if score >= 70:
              letter = 'C'
          else:    
              if score >= 60:
                  letter = 'D'
              else:
                  letter = 'F'
    return letter

for value in range(len(letter_grades)):
    letter_grades[value]=letter_grades[value].replace("X",Gradecalc(student_grades[value]))

print(letter_grades)
```

the result is: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'B']